# Formatting number for reporting services

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I need to format a number, which is zero if its value should be presented as a guided '-', the problem is that this format is that if the figure is for example 0.7 I formatted as follows: ', 7 'As I can avoid this? This is the format I'm using:   ### ### ###.## ;(0.00);'-'

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really not certain of this, and don't have an instance to test it on right now, but I think it's this:

```
### ### ##0.## ;(0.00);'-'
```